# Printing Object Values In Java

Tags: java, eclipse, object

With the code

```
package items;

public class itemtest {

static itemobject[] item = new items[10];
    {
    items[0] = new Toy("Example ID","Example Desc");
    items[1] = new Toy("Second Example ID", " Second Example Desc");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
{
String tid = items[0].exampleiD;
 System.out.print(tid);
}
}
```

I get the error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at items.itemtest.main(itemtest.java:17)
```

on the code line: `String tid = item[0].exampleID;`

Sorry I'm very new to java, could anyone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: As shown, this ought not to compile, as the variable is called "item" in one place and "items" in another, and a class is called "itemobject" in one place and "items" in another. If you want us to tell you what's wrong you need to cut and paste your *actual code* -- a copy full of typos like this isn't good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 {
    items[0] = new Toy("Example ID","Example Desc");
    items[1] = new Toy("Second Example ID", " Second Example Desc");
 }
```

You need to precede this block with the word `static` to have it take effect when the class is loaded -- which is what you actually want to happen, based on your code -- as opposed to when a new instance of `itemobject` is created, which never happens in your code.

Comment: Well, yes, the typos too -- although clearly the actual code in the OP's IDE doesn't have those typos, if the OP actually got a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Sorry excuse my ignorance I don't quite understand ?

Comment: Which part don't you understand?

Comment: "You need to precede this block with the word static".

im really sorry guys I know im no good at this but im trying.

Comment: Add the word `static` before the open bracket in the code segment I quoted.

Answer (score 0):

From your code snippet I assume that you think you are trying to do the following:

- Declare an array of items
- Initialize the the first two items with Toy objects
- Get the first item of the array and print it

The problem in the code is:

- You declare items array as `static` field
- You have an instance initialization block where you initialize the array
- You have a main function where you get the item and  print it

The problem is that the initialization block is done at initialization of *instances*. The main method however is a `static` method and has no instance. Therefore the block has not been called yet and you get a NPE.

You need to make the initialization block also `static` like this:

```
static {
    items[0] = new Toy...
    items[1] = new Toy...
}
```

A `static` initialization block is called once when the class is initialized. So that way it is called before main will be run.